# Why my program doesn't work when I put an Even Number of Elements

Tags: c++, c, arrays, binary-search

I'm trying to make a binary search program and my coding is below but when I ever I give an Even Number of Elements it does not gives any output and when I gives odd no of elements the program works great!! The program first compare the middle value if is false then it compares with less or greater than the  middle value

```
int main()
{
    int n,a[50] ;
    int i, j, temp,counter,searchv,f,l,mid;
    cout<<"Enter no. of elements: ";
    cin>>n;
    f=0;
    l=n-1;
    mid=(f+l)/2;
    cout<<"l= "<<l<<" mid= "<<mid<<"\n";
    cout<<"Enter "<<n <<" values \n";
    for(counter=0;counter<n;counter++)
    {
        cin>>a[counter];
    }

    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        for (int i=(n-1); i>j ;i--)
        {
            if (a[i]<a[i-1])
            {
                int temp=a[i-1];
                a[i-1]=a[i];
                a[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"SORTED ARRAY!!\n";
    for(counter=f;counter<n;counter++)
    {
        cout<<"Value at Element "<<counter <<" is "<<a[counter];

        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Enter number to search: ";
    cin>>searchv;

    if(a[mid]==searchv)
    {
        cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<mid;
    }
    else if(searchv>a[mid])
    {
        for(counter=l;counter>mid;counter--)
        {
            if(a[counter]==searchv)
                cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<counter;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(searchv<a[mid])
    {
        for(counter=0;counter<mid;counter++)
        {
            if(a[counter]==searchv)
                cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<counter;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Value not found\n";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's only a half-hearted attempt at a binary search: You use the fact that the array is sorted only at the top level; after that it's a plain linear search. And you never report failure, because the last `else` clause should never be entered.

Comment: I realize this is likely academic, but [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) may be considerably more convenient (and less error-prone). If nothing else it should be educational to read the possible implementation notes in understanding how an iterative binary-search algorithm can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer above, you can add this

instead of

```
if(a[mid]==searchv)
    {
    cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<mid;
    }
    else if(searchv>a[mid])
    {
    for(counter=l;counter>mid;counter--)
    {
        if(a[counter]==searchv)
    cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<counter;
    break;
    }
    }
    else if(searchv<a[mid])
    {
    for(counter=0;counter<mid;counter++)
    {
    if(a[counter]==searchv)
    cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<<counter;
    break;
    }
    }

else
{
     cout<<"Value not found\n";
}
```

You may try this:

```
    bool isFound = false;

    for(counter=0;counter<l;counter++)
    {
        if(a[counter]==searchv)
        {
            cout<<"searched value "<<searchv<<" founded at position "<< counter << endl;
            isFound = true;

        }
    }

    if (isFound == false)
    {
        cout << "No result found." << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't have anything to do with whether the array has an even or odd number of elements. In your two linear-search loops, e.g.:

```
    for (counter = l; counter > mid; counter--) {
        if (a[counter] == searchv)
            cout << "searched value " << searchv <<
                " founded at position " << counter << '\n';
        break;
    }
```

you `break` out of the loop unconditionally. That means that you test only the first element of the range. You want to break only if you have found a match, of course, so you should use braces:

```
    for (counter = l; counter > mid; counter--) {
        if (a[counter] == searchv) {
            cout << "searched value " << searchv <<
                " founded at position " << counter << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Such errors are easier to spot if you make a habit of indenting consistently and of using braces, maybe except with the most basic `if`s that don't have an `else`.

With this fix, your program will report only matches, but no falures, because the lase `else` can logically never occur, because the previous three `if`/`else`s cover all possible cases. (For integers, `a == b`, `a < b` and `a > b` cover all cases.)

You can repair this by keeping an extra variable that tells you whether a match has been found or by refactoring the search into a separate function, which is advisable anyway.

Comment: If I put " Value not found " in else of IF statement in loop it will work but it will print " Value not found " till the loop ends

Comment: You can only know that the value hasn't been found after you have checked all array elements (or, in a binary search, all elements that could logically be the value). That's why printing the "not found" message must occur at the end, but it must also make use of information whether a value has been found or not.

Comment: @M Oehm Why i cant call my program a binary search?

Comment: I have corrected it and now it print "not found " only one time

Comment: Because it isn't. Your program is a linear search with the exception that it cuts the array in half before searching. That's still O(n). You add that the overhead of sorting, which is O(n log n), making your search even less efficient than linear search. If you have 1 million elements, you still have to compare 500,000 elements in your code. A real binary search would make use of the sorted property array thoughout and it woul need about 20 comparisons (because 2^20 is 1,048,576). Binary search is O(log n).

Comment: There are many example implementations around for binary search. If you study them, you will see, that you find the mid value of the subarrays repeatedly: Is the value at mid? Bingo. is is smaller: Do a binary search on [low:mid - 1]. Is it higher? Do a binary search of [mid + 1:high]. Is the array empty? Value isn't found. Create an array of, say, all even numbers up to 100 and print out the elements that you compare. You will see that you need more comparisons for this small array than a real binary search would for an array of 1 million elements.

Comment: Thankx for all the information :) Our teacher just told us that binary search checks the middle value if its false then go for less or greater and I start making without any futher knowledge..

Comment: Your teacher is right: You check the middle, but you do so repeatedly until you find something or until your subarray is exhausted.